# Error typeScript: 'Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.'

Tags: javascript, typescript

tengo un error Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword. cuando intento declarar una instancia de una función.
Busque en google pero este mensaje aparece en varios errores distintos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funcion:

```
export default function Default() {
    let object: objeto;
    let $el: any = {};
    let config: any = {};
    let color: any = {};
    let maskTitle: (text: string, datamap: any[]) => string = function(value) { return value };

    object.render = function(valuesLeyend, dataMap: any[]) {

        let legend = $el.selectAll(".legend")
            .data(valuesLeyend.slice())
            .enter().append("div")
            .attr("class", "legend g-row")
            .style("font-family", "Roboto")
            .style('margin', '2px');
            
        legend.append("div")
                .style("width", "15px")
                .style("height", "15px")
                .style("background", color);

        legend.append("div")
            .style("font-size", config.fontSize+"px")
            .style("padding", "0 10px")
            .style("width", "90%")
            .style("overflow", "hidden")
            .style("text-overflow", "ellipsis")
            .style("white-space", "nowrap")
            .html((d) =>{return maskTitle(d,dataMap)});
        return object;
    }

    object.$el = function(value){
        if (!arguments.length) return $el;
        $el = value;
        return object;
    };

    object.config = function(value){
        if (!arguments.length) return config;
        config = value;
        return object;
    };

    object.color = function(value){
        if (!arguments.length) return color;
        color = value;
        return object;
    };
    
    object.maskTitle = function(value){
        if (!arguments.length) return maskTitle;
        maskTitle = value;
        return object;
    }; 
    return object;
}

interface objeto {
    render: (value, datamap: any[]) => any;
    $el: (value) => any;
    config: (value) => any;
    color: (value) => any;
    maskTitle: (value) => any; 
}
```

La función tiene que retornar obligatoriamente para que funcione como fue pensada originalmente en JS. Actualmente estoy pasando a typeScript y si quiero respetar tal cual como esta en js no me queda otra que preservar la funcion pero me encontre con este error que parece no admitir returns.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que toda la aplicacion usa function. Lo mismo que me comentas lo hice con 2 archivos y funciono perfecto pero bueno.. estaria cambiando la forma en que esta hecho. Quisiera contemplar una en donde no tenga que cambiarlo.

Comment: Ademas me pasa que hay archivos muy grandes con muchos metodos y si lo paso a class voy a tener que agregar los "this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te indica que *"solo funciones que no retornan nada pueden llamarse con la palabra clave 'new'"*.

En tu caso solo deberías cambiar esto:

```
let legend = new Default;
```

Por esto:

```
let legend = Default();
```

Comment: Perfecto marcos eso mismo era. 
Gracias.